My github action runners seem to run out of space?
Recently on a project, I started running into my github action runners running low on space.  This was for the execution period (I have a build step, then a run step, with an artifact of the apk between).
Thought it was odd, but I used uses: jlumbroso/free-disk-space@main to help free up a lot of default stuff that the free runners have, and it seemed to solve the issue.
Then recently the build step of the app also started running out of space.  I run it on ubuntu-latest, which according to the docs should give me 14Gb of storage.
However, somehow, building a single reactnative mobile app is causing me to run out of space?:

stderr: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not add entry ':app:fullstoryDevelopmentRelease' to cache executionHistory.bin (/home/runner/work/mobile-app/mobile-app/android/.gradle/8.0.1/executionHistory/executionHistory.bin).
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:162)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.lambda$put$1(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:67)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:216)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:206)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$UnitOfWorkFileAccess.writeFile(DefaultCacheAccess.java:471)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.put(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:67)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache.lambda$putLater$1(AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker$2.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:247)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:228)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.flushOperations(CacheAccessWorker.java:175)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:145)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore.write(FileBackedBlockStore.java:140)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CachingBlockStore.flush(CachingBlockStore.java:64)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FreeListBlockStore.flush(FreeListBlockStore.java:103)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.StateCheckBlockStore.flush(StateCheckBlockStore.java:85)
stdout: 
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:160)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.write(RandomAccessFile.java:558)
    at org.gradle.internal.io.RandomAccessFileOutputStream.write(RandomAccessFileOutputStream.java:46)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:153)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.ByteOutput.done(ByteOutput.java:62)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore$BlockImpl.write(FileBackedBlockStore.java:223)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.FileBackedBlockStore.write(FileBackedBlockStore.java:136)
    ... 22 more

FAILURE: Build completed with 3 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-safe-area-context:prepareLintJarForPublish'.
> Failed to create parent directory '/home/runner/work/mobile-app/mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/build/intermediates/lint_publish_jar' when creating directory '/home/runner/work/mobile-app/mobile-app/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android/build/intermediates/lint_publish_jar/global'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDevelopmentRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > java.io.IOException: No space left on device


The free runners definitely have limitations. Have you rolled out your own runner to measure the actual memory usage of the program you’re working on? If not, that's the homework now.

What runner are you using? What is the value of runs-on for the job?

@LexLi the thing is, it was working fine a week ago.  Nothing's changed as far as I can tell.  I added in a uses: jlumbroso/free-disk-space@main when it first started, and that solved it for a while, but now it's back.

@DeltaGeorge runs-on ubuntu-latest.

You might guarantee no changes on your side, but the free runners can change significantly without notice. Overall, you have little control over that.

is your clean flag set to true in your github actions file??

Could you clarify?  I thought it spun a new runner each time?

can you add me to you repo i will see the pipline and let you know where to set it
